# How to create an instance of a class using only the interface

Tags: c#, interface, n-tier-architecture

I have an application with client, Library and Interface as a middle layer. The classes in the Library implement the Interface.I want to call the library without having to reference it. So I dont have to do this:

```
IInterface myClass = new Library.MyClass();
```

One way is to use Unity I guess. Is there any other way? Somehow the whole idea of the Interface fades away right now.

Thanks

Comment: what you mean under "I want to call the library without having to reference it"?

Comment: Well the Interfaces is there for that reason. The client shouldn't bother with Library1, Library2, Library3. If I am to call directly a new instance of the Library then i lose the Interface's purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. 
One, through the use of Dependency Inversion, as you show with Unity, and the other by writing class factories, and lastly, as you've mentioned, newing up the class instance, which is not really helpful at all :)

My own personal taste tends to Dependency Inversion, where [Structuremap](http://structuremap.github.io/) is my favourite IoC Container. Very easy to set up, and very easy to use, but most of the IoC Containers are very well documented.

The thing you typically end up with are something to the likes of:

```
IInterface myClass = myContainer.GetInstanceOf<IInterface>();
```

Comment: dosnt this requier a reference?

Comment: Not directly. Most containers allow you to load up all DLL's that contain implementations and they can then resolve Interfaces to implementations by themselves. So for the configuration of IoC, you would typically just tell the container to add this dll and that dll, the container does the rest.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used the Factory pattern so far. Will dig a bit more before accepting your answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, the library is not a third party component and you can change the implementation!? If so, i would suggest to use [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is part of the .Net framework and supports exactly what you want - loading components from other assemblies that are not necessarily referenced.

In your library, you have to declare the class to use in you app with an export attribute:

```
[Export(typeof(IInterface))] class MyClass : IInterface{ }
```

And in your client application, you can import the component with:

```
[Import(typeof(IInterface))] public IInterface myClase;
```

And finally you can compose all imports and exports:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

// add assamby by type
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof (AnyType).Assembly));

// add assembly by path
// this example adds all assembly in the current directory that ends with "Extension.dll".
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@".", "*Extensions.dll"));
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

// compose parts: MEF composes all imports and exports
container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is usually being done by using `Factory` design pattern.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
}

public class A : IMyInterface
{
    internal A() // so, the user/developer won't be able to call "var a = new A()" outside of the scope of the assembly
    {
    }
}

public class B : IMyInterface
{
    internal B()
    {
    }
}

public static class MyFactory
{
    public static IMyInterface CreateA()
    {
        return new A();
    }

    public static IMyInterface CreateB()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
static void Main()
{
    IMyInterface a = MyFactory.CreateA(); // instance of A
    IMyInterface b = MyFactory.CreateB(); // instance of B
}
```

If you are creating an API, you can set the constructor of `A` and `B` to internal, so the developer won't be able to create an instance of them without using the Factory.

*Note: you can use the factory to store the created instance, so it will return the same instance rather then creating a new one every single time.*

Comment: Thank you for the example, it was very helpful! I have accepted Pedro's answer though because it provides more options to deal with the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help! That answer get's the job done from the Dependency Injection's perspective, while mine is a Design Pattern, so they could work together simultaneously - especially if you are creating API as well. For the question, that answer is better. :)